# Replacing object's name inside another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which serves as parameter that I pass on to the jquery validator plugin:

```
var  param = {rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        tel: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
       }
     };
```

I have three forms which have have similar fields, yet they are named like `'xxx[name]'`,`'xxx[tel]'`, etc. I need to write a function that would replace the name of the object inside the param object, but for some reason i'm confused as to how I can do that. I've tried:

```
function insertParam(par1) {
     var  param = {rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        tel: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
       }
     };

 param['rules']['name'] = param['rules'][par1 + '[name]'];
 param['rules']['tel'] = param['rules'][par1 + '[tel]'];

 return param;
 };
```

But this doesn't work. So, how is this done properly? Will appreciate any feedback.

EDIT: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qzgaS/

Comment: `param.rules.name = param.rules[par1[name]]`?

Comment: I don't think that would work

Comment: It is not entirely clear what part1 is, but in case that it has a `name` property, `param.rules.name = param.rules[par1.name]`, which is similar to what @mishik suggested, only he also mistakenly mixed the notations. If not, can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your intentions?

Comment: @MasterAM par1 is a the xxx that I pass as a parameter to the function so that it would replace the name and tel fields of the object. In example, if i pas 'Call' as par1, the function should return Call[name] and Call[tel] as the names of those fields of the object param.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle or expand the question with all relevant HTML and JS, as I cannot understand exactly what is passed where and what, precisely, is the desired output.

Comment: @MasterAM added fiddle.

Comment: Please show us the desired output for your function when you invoke it with `"Call"`!

Comment: The `param.rules` object does not have a `Call[name]` property. Perhaps you wanted to get something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgaS/1/)?

Comment: param = { rules: { Call[name]: {}, Call[tel]: {} }

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed assignment order and notations.

Since you are using some 'special' (e.g, `[`) characters in your property names, you should use the bracket notation.

Otherwise, for constant properties, use

```
foo.bar
```

instead of

```
foo['bar']
```

for better readability.

You wanted to generate a parameter object from a template. This can be done by constructing an object with the desired properties and assigning the template's values to them, as such:

```
function insertParam(par1) {
     var  rules = {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        tel: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    };

    var result = {"rules":{}};
    result.rules[par1 + '[name]'] = rules.name;
    result.rules[par1 + '[tel]'] = rules.tel;

    return result;
};
```

When called it will produce the desired output:

```
>>> insertParam('Call')

{
    "rules": {
        "Call[name]": {
            "required": true
        },
        "Call[tel]": {
            "required": true,
            "number": true
        }
    }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgaS/1/)